# Rails: Get the controller and action of the current request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails application, I use `<html id=<%= params[:controller] + "_" + params[:action] %>` in views/layouts/application.html.erb.

The strange thing is, the values of `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]` always lag by 1 request **if it is anywhere above the opening `<body>` tag.**

So if I'm on `users/1`, but I came from `users/`, the values above opening `<body>` will be controller: "users" and action: "index". Shouldn't `params[:action]` be "show"?.

Then if I refresh the page, it 'catches up' and correctly has controller: "users" and action: "show".

Why is this happening? How can I get the current requests controller and action? Will these params not be updated until the first time `yield` is called?

Comment: How about `<html id="<%= "#{params[:controller]}_#{params[:action]}" %>">` ?

Comment: debug the controller thats rendering this layout and see what the values actually are.

Comment: editted question - debugging shows correct values after opening body tag, but lagged values before the opening body tag.

Comment: are you using turbolinks?

Comment: ....yea. this is the 2nd time turbolinks has caused one of these crazy bugs. Are the performance gains from turbolinks really worth it? It seems to make doing simple things, for example this, difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was turbolinks. Turn off turbolinks and you're good to go. http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4

Comment: Bloody turbolinks. With modern browser and connection speeds I really wonder whether they're worth the hassle.

Comment: Foiled again by Turbolinks! You can turn off Turbolinks for a specific link also: `link_to 'Logout', logout_users_path, method: :delete, "data-no-turbolink" => true`.

Answer (score 47):

For the controller, you have access to the local instance `controller`.
If you want the full name of it, you'll need to use something like `controller.class.name.split("::").first` which will give you `UsersController` in your example. If you just wanted `users` to be returned you could use `controller.controller_name`

For the action you can use `controller.action_name`

UPDATE:

Please try these in your view and see if they're also lagging:

```
<p><%= controller_name %></p>
<p><%= action_name %></p>
```

I suspect they both delegate to the controller mentioned earlier in my answer, but it's worth trying.

Comment: They also lag. I just noticed they only don't lag if I put it inside content returned within application.html.erb's <% yield %>.

Comment: Could this relate to the "yield" block? Maybe instance variables aren't updated until after the yield starts? That might explain why `<html id=<%= controller_name %>` can have a different value than "some_var".

Comment: FYI in Rails 4.2 I just used `action_name`... `controller.action_name` didn't work