# Rescuing LoadError in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.8.7

In my Rails 3 app, I am fetching path_info by:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(url, { :method => request.request_method }) rescue {}
```

If a crawler hits a URL like "http://localhost:3000/admin_", the above code raises following error:

```
LoadError: Expected /Users/user/myRailsApp/app/controllers/admin_controller.rb to define Admin_Controller
from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant'
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is `rescue` not working? If I change it to `rescue LoadError => e`, exception is handled gracefully.
2. Is there any other alternative rather than rescuing such exception(s)?

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the exception type, by default `rescue` will rescue only `StandardError` exceptions and subclasses.

`LoadError` doesn't inherit from `StandardError`:

```
LoadError.ancestors
 => [LoadError, ScriptError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Therefore, the one-line rescue pattern doesn't work with a `LoadError`.

Comment: Thanks. It answers the first question. What about the second one? It there any alternative to handle such URLs?

Comment: I can't understand why you fetch the path info in that way rather using `request.env['PATH_INFO']`

Comment: `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` gives me a hash with `controller` and `action` as keys. I need this hash to do some further processing. This works even for custom routes. `request.env['PATH_INFO']` doesn't give me that.

Comment: In the controller you can access `controller_name` and `action_name` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399663/rails-get-the-controller-and-action-of-the-current-request

Comment: I have to fetch the path_info in a `lib` file to get this working: https://github.com/bendiken/rack-throttle/blob/master/lib/rack/throttle/limiter.rb#L6. Can't thus use `path_info` in controller. Please let me know if you need more details.